# One event multiple times Full Calendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I build a project with full calendar scheduler library, and I have `timelineMonth` view where I render events based on week, so I wrote it like this:

```
views: {
    timelineMonth: {

      slotLabelFormat: [
        'WW'
      ],
      slotDuration: {
        weeks: 1
      },

    },
```

And it shows timeline month with weeks, one slot is considered 1 week, and if one event is displayed in 7 days , it shows it 7 times in the week slot, so what I want to do is displaying event only once in that week in the `timelineMonth` view, why it is showing multiple times.HAs anyone an idea how to do this, thank you in advance

Comment: "if one event is displayed in 7 days". It's not completely clear what you mean by this. Do you mean you have 7 event objects in your JSON, and they occur within the same week? If so then yes of course there will be 7 things displayed - they are 7 separate events. If you only want to display one event, then in your JSON you need to have one single event object covering 7 days. The slot duration you set does not affect this, it only changes the way the grid is displayed.

Comment: @ADyson it should overwrite the first event, for example if i add a User and i set him working days in Monday and Tuesday, then I add the same User but now i set working days Thurstday and Friday, it ads the same user twice but it should overwrite the first or just add the new days to the first, do you understand me

Comment: Why should it overwrite anything? Fullcalendar will display whatever events you give it. It doesn't know anything about your bespoke business rules relating to users working hours. To the calendar they're just events. If they're in the JSON event list it will display them. If you don't want something to be displayed, then don't include it in the event list. If you have a situation where events are added to the calendar via the UI, and in certain circumstances it should cause some other event to change, or disappear, then you have to implement that custom logic yourself.